# Can not change anything on vsftpd.conf

Tags: vsftpd

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and need to setup FTP on it, I tried to configure FTP on the first OS account (Type: administrator), opened vsftpd.conf and changed something on it for FTP, but couldn't save, it showed "you don't have permission".

And also how to remote my Ubuntu desktop from outside (which way, port, ...).
I'm a beginner.
Pls help.

Thanks and Best Regards,
Thanh Vo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the file as root user or with sudo `sudo nano vsftpd.conf`.
Remote access to your system can be done via ssh: `ssh user@server`

If you have a graphical desktop you want to view use x11 forwarding.
Make sure X11 forwarding is enabled on the server: `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
The line `X11Forwarding` must be set to `yes`.
Then `ssh -X username@server` on your client.

Comment: I suggest you replace vim with nano and nano with gedit, considering the inexperience of the OP.